# Jasmine `toThrowError` Typescript definition (d.ts) appears to be missing a 3rd signature

Tags: typescript, jasmine

I've written some tests in Typescript using the `jasmine/index.d.ts`.

There are several tests that use `toThrowError` to assert that a specific custom Error Class has been thrown.

All the tests pass, but the TS compiler is throwing the following error:

`error TS2345: Argument of type 'typeof MyCustomError' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Error'.`

I've checked the jasmine docs and unless i'm misunderstanding, the first argument can be an Error Class.

`expect(foo).toThrowError(TypeError);`

But the `jasmine index.d.ts` only lists 2 signatures for `toThrowError`:

`toThrowError(message?: string | RegExp): boolean;`

`toThrowError(expected?: Error, message?: string | RegExp): boolean;`

My understanding of TS is still a little shaky, but i'm wondering if there should also be a third signature that allows the first argument to be a Class that extends Error, rather than an instance? Something like:

`toThrowError(expected?: typeof Error, message?: string | RegExp): boolean;`

I say 'something like' as i've tried adding this to the `.d.ts`, but then get the following error:

`error TS2345: Argument of type 'typeof MyCustomError' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ErrorConstructor'.`

---

**Custom Error Class**

```
class MyCustomError extends Error {

    constructor() {
        super('A custom error message.');
    }
}
```

**Test logic**

```
it('should throw an error', () => {

    var obj = new MyObject();

    expect(() => obj.doSomething()
        .toThrowError(MyCustomError);
});
```

---

**Current solution to prevent TS error**

If i make the error an instance, the the TS error stops.

```
it('should throw an error', () => {

    var obj = new MyObject();

    expect(() => obj.doSomething()
        .toThrowError(new MyCustomError());
});
```

---

**UPDATE**

```
it('should throw an error', () => {

    var obj = new MyObject();

    expect(() => obj.doSomething()
        .toThrowError(TypeError);
});
```

So i've found that if i change the Error type in the test to `TypeError` my IDE (Webstorm) and the TS compiler both complain (and my test correctly fails):

`Argument type TypeErrorConstructor is not assignable to parameter type Error`

But if i then re-add the previous 3rd signature to `jasmine/index.d.ts` then both the IDE and TS compiler are happy.

`toThrowError(expected?: typeof Error, message?: string | RegExp): boolean;`

Which suggest that the `d.ts` is missing a signature and my custom Error Class is declared incorrectly?

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a bug in the tsd.

Jasmine [docs](https://jasmine.github.io/edge/introduction.html#section-Included_Matchers) certainly did not indicate you can pass an instance of `Error` to `toThrowError()`. The signature should be changed to `typeof Error`.

You can file an issue on DefinitelyTyped, but if you wanted it fixed faster, better file a pull request with the original Jasmine example as test code.

Comment: Thanks, it looks like this issue has already been fixed in the latest jasmine.d.ts - `toThrowError(expected?: new (...args: any[]) => Error, message?: string | RegExp): boolean;`